# references are a pain for my mocks in TDD

Tags: c++, tdd, googletest

I am new with c++/tdd, embraced gtest/gmock, and fell in love.
One thing kind of puzzles me though. Are reference pointers really the way to go?

I find myself producing a lot of boiler plate injecting all mocks (even when I don't have any business mocking *that* behavior).

Example:

```
namespace
{
    class set_configuration_command_tests : public testing::Test
    {
        protected:

        void SetUp() override
        {
            _uart_peripheral = new uart8_peripheral_mock();
            _uart = new uart8_mock(*_uart_peripheral);
            _logger =  new logger_mock(*_uart);
            _mqtt_client = new mqtt_client_mock(*_logger);
            _set_configuration_command = new set_configuration_command(*_mqtt_cient);
        }

        void TearDown() override
        {
            delete _set_configuration_command;
        }

        uart8_peripheral_mock *_uart_peripheral;
        uart8_mock *_uart;
        logger_mock *_logger;
        mqtt_client_mock *_mqtt_cient;

        set_configuration_command *_set_configuration_command;
    };

    TEST_F(set_configuration_command_tests, execute_update_configuration)
    {
        // arrange
        // act
        // assert
    }
}
```

What I rather did here, is create my sut as

```
_mqtt_client = new mqtt_client_mock(nullptr); // will not compile of course
_set_configuration_command = new set_configuration_command(*_mqtt_cient);
```

All the other mocks, I don't need in this case.

Is this the drawback of using reference pointers? Or is there a better approach I should follow?

Comment: While you're not violating the language standard with this particular usage of identifiers with underscore prefixes, it still feels uneasy to see them.  Consider using a different style for your member variables if you want readers of your code to trust you.

Comment: @paddy The underscore prefix very often indicates private/protected member variables in C++, there's nothing "uneasy" about them.

Comment: Not sure what is your issue here: if `mqtt_client` requires to have `logger` (only one ctor with logger reference) then you are forced to create mock for it. If you are considering scenario when `mqtt_client` can exist without `logger` - you can either add extra ctor or just setter method for `mqtt_client`.

Comment: @Bert - I'm with @paddy here, and feel uneasy, or at least it slows down the reading. We know that leading underscore is reserved for the implementaion only in the global namespace.  Using the same naming for local names forces me (and paddy) to stop and consider if `_uart` could be a compiler extension.

Comment: @jdfa thx for the tip. I am not really looking for an approach where I either need  to add constructors or setter methods for testing purpose. found a way after all.

Comment: @paddy, sorry to make you feel uneasy :). I am used to C# where this is the default. I also have seen some code where the postfix members with underscore. But since you brought it up, mind telling me what makes you less uneasy? Still learning c++, don't mind adapting the proper coding standards but I see soooo many different styles that it's hard to see "the one"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better alternative. Providing interfaces (pure virtual classes) heavily reduces the need to provide an entire tree of mocks.

e.g

```
class flash_api : public iflash_api
{
    public:
    flash_api(iflash_peripheral &flash_peripheral) : _flash_peripheral(flash_peripheral)
    {
    }

    virtual ~flash_api()
    {
    }
}
```

Before my mock inherited from `flash_api` directly. When I gave this class an interface too (`iflash_api') I can let my mock inherit from iflash_api, which gives me a parameter-less constructor.

```
class flash_api_mock : public iflash_api
{
    public:
    flash_api_mock()
    {
    }

    virtual ~flash_api_mock()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I can write my unit test based on the mocks I actually want to give  behavior.

```
class set_configuration_command_tests : public testing::Test
{
    protected:

    void SetUp() override
    {
        _mqtt_cient = new mqtt_client_mock();
        _flash_api = new flash_api_mock();
        _set_configuration_command = new set_configuration_command(*_mqtt_cient, *_flash_api);
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
        delete _set_configuration_command;
    }

    flash_api_mock *_flash_api;
    mqtt_client_mock *_mqtt_cient;

    set_configuration_command *_set_configuration_command;
};
```

Comment: Avoid heap allocation whenever possible - here `_set_configuration_command` can be just a `set_configuration_command`, no need for a pointer here. Also, please consider using `unique_ptr` for dependency injection.

Comment: @Quarra yes to all. thx for the googleable learnings!! heard of smart pointers before, never used them. there is almost no difference anymore with C# :)